# How to serialize a type derived from List as an array-like object with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Consider the following class deriving from `List`:

```
public class Foo : List<string>
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing it with JSON.NET dumps the `Bar` property and produces a regular array:

```
var foo = new Foo() { "a", "b", "c" };
foo.Bar = "baz";
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo); // ["a","b","c"]
```

What can I do to obtain the following array-like object as the result of my serialization?

```
{"0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c", "length": 3, "bar": "baz"}
```

Is a custom serializer the only way to go or is there a JSON.NET setting that can do this for me?

Comment: What kind of settings do you expect for a very specialized case like this?

Comment: I was hoping that deriving a collection was not *that* specialized and could be handled by the framework.

Comment: Vache, but the json you expect is a very specialized.....

Comment: @Vache: instead of inheritance you could try encapsulation.  As long as you are ok with that being reflected in the json.

Comment: @Eser, it's a simple array-like object, a concept often seen in JavaScript

Comment: @SamAxe: Indeed. In my use case it actually makes sense to derive the `List` but I'm certainly keeping that solution in mind if it gets too complicated to serialize

Comment: Vache, but not the one to expect when serializing a standard list or object.

Comment: @Eser: Which is why I thought it was not such a wild idea to have a setting that is not activated by default. I understand that you wouldn't want that everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think the **easiest way** to get what you are looking for, is to do something like this:

```
var foo = new Foo() { "a", "b", "c" };
foo.Bar = "baz";

var data = foo
    .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
    .ToDictionary(wrapper => wrapper.index.ToString(), wrapper => (object)wrapper.value);

data.Add("length", foo.Count);
data.Add("bar", foo.Bar);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
//{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","length":3,"bar":"baz"}
```

A **more generic way** to solve this problem for all elements with any amount of properties would be this Code:

```
var foo = new Foo() { "a", "b", "c" };
foo.Bar = "baz";
foo.Beer = "beer";

var json = GetJsonWithItemsAndProperties(foo);
//{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","length":3,"Bar":"baz","Beer":"beer"}

//...//

private static string GetJsonWithItemsAndProperties<T>(IReadOnlyCollection<T> listWithProperties)
{
    var data = listWithProperties
        .Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
        .ToDictionary(wrapper => wrapper.index.ToString(), wrapper => (object) wrapper.value);

    data.Add("length", data.Count);

    listWithProperties.GetType()
        .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList()
        .ForEach(p => data.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(listWithProperties)));

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
```

Comment: What about the `"bar": "baz"` and `"length": 3` part?

Comment: That yields `{"0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c"}` which is quite different from what I'm looking for. The length (required for an array-like object) and the derived property are missing.

Comment: I've updated my code to also include `"bar": "baz"` and `"length": "3"`

Comment: @DavidLeitner Do you think it is good solution now? OK, it works for these foos and bars, but what about if the class have different properties and there would be many classes like it?

Comment: @Vache As you said, `Is a custom serializer the only way to go` . Yes It is (I mean a custom JsonConverter. Just google for it).

Comment: @Eser: Of course you can make it more generic, but then I think List<> doesn't provide enough information. A good solution would be to add an interface, or if this isn't possible, getting the property value and name of the object via reflection would be another way to solve this.